# Node.JS using Sails.JS Framework -- Passport: no strategy registered under name: facebook

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, passport.js

I'm using the Sails.JS framework for Node.JS . I have written a config/middleware.js that has a verify handler and makes the initial connection. The page is currently erroring on the AuthController that is being pushed by config/routes.js.

Console Log:

> ```
> Fired Facebook 
> error: Error: no strategy registered under name: facebook
> at attempt (/project/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:237:37)
> at Passport.authenticate (/project/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:244:7)
> at AuthController.facebook (/project/api/controllers/AuthController.js:35:4)
> ```

Authcontroller.js function

```
   'facebook': function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Fired Facebook");
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: '/auth',
    scope: 'email'
    }, function(err, user) {
       console.log("Fired Login Attempt");
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.view('500');
                    return;
                    }

            res.redirect('home/index');
            return;
            });
    })(req, res, next);
```

---

Passport-facebook and passport are both in the node-modules.

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "sails": "0.9.4",
    "grunt": "0.4.1",
    "sails-disk": "~0.9.0",
    "ejs": "0.8.4",
    "optimist": "0.3.4",
    "passport": "latest",
    "passport-local": "latest",
    "passport-facebook":"latest",
    "sails-mongo":"latest",
    "bcrypt": "0.7.6"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved -- Conflicting node_modules of passport were installed.

Comment: Which ones? Having the same problem.